# Set background image and icon image in iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone-6

How can I differentiate the background images and icon images between the different resolutions for the iPhone 5 and for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus?

Comment: For icon and image sizes these are the specified sizes by apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html specifically for iPhone6 there is no update yet i guess.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to turn on iOS 8 sizes in your image catalogs. They're off by default in existing projects:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strange - I don't see anything like this in my Xcode project. I have a single "App Icons and Launch Images" section and only a place to specify the "App Icons Source", "Launch Images Source", and "Launch Screen File". There are no checkboxes.

Comment: Update - I just found this. It's in the attributes inspector (down array icon) of the right (Utilities) pane (which I rarely display) when viewing the LaunchImage asset.

Comment: @Sidnicious It works very well with app icons and launch images. But what about UIView's background? I use 
`[[self navigationController].view insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]] atIndex:0];`
to set background and it doesn't work with iPhone 6, because there is no possibility to set proper image for its resolution in .xcassets.