# Simulator running in scaling mode for iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

My app starts and runs on the new iPhone 6 Plus (or iPhone 6) in the simulator, but elements that I know are supposed to be small on the big screen (i.e. hard coded `CGRect`s) are large, as if the whole app had just been scaled up for the larger screen.

How can I get out of scaling mode in the simulator?

Comment: Yes, our old app uses hard coded CGRect are all fine with large screen. Not sure why is that. Must be a scaling mode

Answer (score 19):

It looks like setting a launch screen file in the "App Icons and Launch Images" section of your project settings, or adding iOS 8 images to your launch image catalog, will enable "native" resolution.

Comment: Any idea what resolutions are required here?

Comment: @Nick 750x1334 for Retina HD 4.7 and 1242x2208 for Retina HD 5.5.

Comment: Oh, and also you have to turn them on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752750/set-background-image-and-icon-image-in-iphone-6-and-6-plus

Comment: I didnt' have to define any images, just populate the drop down menu with the storyboard name. My asset catalog is empty for launch image. It scales great now.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a correctly sized LaunchImage seems to be enough (setting an incorrectly sized image won't).

Also adding the new "Launch Screen File" should work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must set correctly sized LaunchImages
For more information about LaunchImages and icons see this documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 0):

use Asset Catalog Creator from mac app store.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/asset-catalog-creator-app/id809625456?mt=12
```

give it any image and it will generate all the correct launch images and icons in a xassets file.

This should stop the scaling of the whole app on iphone 6+